# How can I modify this script to use different replacement array based on the ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script below.  What I want to do is modify it so that it uses a different set of replacement values depending on what the document.getElementById('something') is.

So ('Headline') would use a different set of replacement characters from ('Body'), etc.

Thanks in advance

```
function DeGlyph(element) {
// List of replacement rules. 
     replacements= [
        //Single Quote Characters
        ['\u0027', '\''],
        ['\u2018', '\''],
        ['\u2019', '\''],
        ['\u201A', '\''],
        ['\u201B', '\''],
        //Double Quote Characters
        ['\u0022', '"'],
        ['\u201C', '"'],
        ['\u201D', '"'],
        ['\u201E', '"'],
        ['\u201F', '"'],
        ['\u301D', '"'],
        ['\u301E', '"'],
        ['\u301F', '"'],
        //Other Characters      
        ['\u00BC', '1/4'],
        ['\u00BD', '1/2'],
        ['\u00BE', '3/4'],
        ['\u2122', '<sup>TM</sup>'],        
        ['\u2013', '-'],
        ['\u2014', '&mdash;'],
        ['\u00A9', '&copy;'],
        ['\u00AE', '&reg;']         


    ];


// Only attempt to use replacer behaviour if we can retain the cursor
// position. Setting value by default moves the cursor to the end of the
// input, which is too irritating.
//
    if (getInputSelection(element)!==null) {
        element.onkeyup= function() {
            value= element.value;
            for (var i= 0; i<replacements.length; i++) {
                value= value.split(replacements[i][0]).join(replacements[i][1]);
            }
            if (value!=element.value) {
                var s= getInputSelection(element);
                element.value= value;
                setInputSelection(element, s);
            }
        };
    }
}

// Cross-browser (as much as possible anyway) cursor positioning
//
function getInputSelection(element) {
    if (element.selectionStart!==window.undefined) {
        return [element.selectionStart, element.selectionEnd];
    } else if (document.selection) {
        var BIG= 1000000;
        var range= document.selection.createRange();
        if (range.moveStart===window.undefined)
            return [0, 0];
        var start= -range.moveStart('character', -BIG);
        var end= -range.moveEnd('character', -BIG);
        return [start-1, end-1];
    } else return null;
}
function setInputSelection(element, s) {
    if (element.selectionStart!==window.undefined) {
        element.selectionStart= s[0];
        element.selectionEnd= s[1];
    } else if (document.selection) {
        var range= element.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd('character', s[1]);
        range.moveStart('character', s[0]);
        range.select();
    }
}

new DeGlyph(document.getElementById('Headline')); 
new DeGlyph(document.getElementById('Body'));
```

Comment: Why not pass the array in as a variable, instead of coding the logic of switching into the function itself?

Comment: Wow ... so where is the jQuery? :P

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, that was some 'fun' - like Chris said, just chuck the function the replacement array you'd like to use, rather than hard-coding it.

It's a simple matter of
(a) altereing the format of the look-up table a little
(b) altering the function sig for DeGlyph to include the replacements array
(c) adding a function that calculates the vars to pass to DeGlyph.

Try this on for size (did it take selecting the text in the input, in addition to losing then regaining focus on the browser window to update? I thought it wasn't working until I selected the original text then did alt-tab back and forth between the browser and another program)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

var mArray = 
    [
        {
                     forId : 'headline', 
            replacements : [
                                //Single Quote Characters
                                ['\u0027', '\''],
                                ['\u2018', '\''],
                                ['\u2019', '\''],
                                ['\u201A', '\''],
                                ['\u201B', '\'']
                            ]
        },


        { 
                     forId : 'body',
            replacements : [
                                ['\u0022', '"'],
                                ['\u201C', '"'],
                                ['\u201D', '"'],
                                ['\u201E', '"'],
                                ['\u201F', '"'],
                                ['\u301D', '"'],
                                ['\u301E', '"'],
                                ['\u301F', '"']
                            ]
        },

        { 
                     forId : 'mTest',
            replacements : [
                                ['1', 'one'],
                                ['2', 'two'],
                                ['3', 'three'],
                                ['4', 'four'],
                                ['5', 'five']
                            ]
        }
    ];




function mDeGlyph(idStr, mDataBank)
{
    var element = document.getElementById(idStr);
    if (element == null)
    {
        alert('no element with that id="'+idStr+'" found');
        return;
    }
    var i, n = mDataBank.length, replacements, found=false;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (mDataBank[i].forId == idStr)
        {
            replacements = mDataBank[i].replacements;
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found == true)
    {
        DeGlyph(element, replacements);
    }
    else
        alert("no apparent entry for that id-string");
}


function DeGlyph(element, replacements) 
{
// Only attempt to use replacer behaviour if we can retain the cursor
// position. Setting value by default moves the cursor to the end of the
// input, which is too irritating.
//
    if (getInputSelection(element)!==null) {
        element.onkeyup= function() {
            value= element.value;
            for (var i= 0; i<replacements.length; i++) {
                value= value.split(replacements[i][0]).join(replacements[i][1]);
            }
            if (value!=element.value) {
                var s= getInputSelection(element);
                element.value= value;
                setInputSelection(element, s);
            }
        };
    }
}

// Cross-browser (as much as possible anyway) cursor positioning
//
function getInputSelection(element) {
    if (element.selectionStart!==window.undefined) {
        return [element.selectionStart, element.selectionEnd];
    } else if (document.selection) {
        var BIG= 1000000;
        var range= document.selection.createRange();
        if (range.moveStart===window.undefined)
            return [0, 0];
        var start= -range.moveStart('character', -BIG);
        var end= -range.moveEnd('character', -BIG);
        return [start-1, end-1];
    } else return null;
}
function setInputSelection(element, s) {
    if (element.selectionStart!==window.undefined) {
        element.selectionStart= s[0];
        element.selectionEnd= s[1];
    } else if (document.selection) {
        var range= element.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd('character', s[1]);
        range.moveStart('character', s[0]);
        range.select();
    }
}

// just displays the list of repoklacements that we have for assorted ids.
function mInit()
{

//  mDeGlyph('Headline');
//  mDeGlyph('Body');
    mDeGlyph('mTest', mArray);
}


</script>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body onload='mInit();'>
    <input id='mTest' value='1 3 5' />
</body>
</html>
```